# Including here.com static image

Tags: mpdf

After adding static here.com map image into my HTML and converting to PDF got this error:

> Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfImageException: Error parsing image file - image
>   type not recognized, and not supported by GD imagecreate

There is no problem regarding showing image in browser.
My link: https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview?app_id={MY_APP_ID}&app_code={MY_APP_CODE}&lat=52.518752&lon=13.402277&vt=0&z=14

If I use Google Map API for static image map convert to PDF works fine.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&key={MY_API_KEY}

UPDATE:
PHP Version 7.0.31 and GD version
[image]

Comment: Please provide your PHP/GD versions and the actual image that fails.

Comment: Updated my question. Printing fails only if I use URL as source of image.

Comment: Still not entirely helpful, cannot assess this without the image or the actual URL.